# Flash - how can i get and send data bypasing flash progam?

Tags: database, flash, decompiler

One site have a Flash application where I can log in and get some information from this app. 
How i can bypass Flash application to get that information ?
Is there any "ezy" way to do it ? or maybe can i check what information is sending to this app and what app is downloading from server ?

Comment: You can decompile the swf using some tools like Sothink decompiler and check the code inside it.